# C# | Одномерный массив | Вывод значений в label через запятую

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется учебная задача.

**Суть:** формируется одномерный массив, который заполняется рандомными значениями. Необходимо: 1) вывести все значения в label через запятую; 2) Создать метод для расчета среднего арифметического среди всех элементов массива.

2-я часть реализована (метод коректно подсчитывает).

**Помогите разобраться с 1-й, каким образом можно вывести значения массива в label при такой реализации?**

Предоставляю свой код:

```
class Arrays // Описание класса
        {
            public bool error = false;
            int[] a;
            int length;
            public Arrays(int size)
            {
                a = new int[size]; length = size;
            }
            public int Length
            {
                get
                {
                    return length;
                }
            }
            public int Average_ari // Метод для расчета среднего арифметического
            {
                get
                {
                    int sum = 0;
                    int avg = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        {
                        sum += a[i];
                        avg = sum / length;
                        }
                    return avg;
                }
            }

            public int this[int i]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (i >= 0 && i < length) return a[i];
                    else
                    {
                        error = true; return 0;
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    if (i >= 0 && i < length && value >= -100 && value <= 100) a[i] = value;
                    else error = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = 100;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            Random ran = new Random();
            try
            {
                n = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
                Arrays a = new Arrays(n);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // заполнение массива рандомными значениями
                {
                    a[i] = ran.Next(-100, 100);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(a[i].ToString());
                }
                if (a.error) MessageBox.Show("Error");
                label2.Text = "Середнє арифметичне масиву: " + a.Average_ari.ToString(); // Вывод среднего арифметического


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
```

Буду благодарен за помощь :)

UPD: По анализу интернета, нашел предложение решения через: Label.Text = string.Join(" ", massiv1); Но не совсем понятно, как его реализовать в этом коде. Если это правильное направление, помогите понять реализацию.

Comment: верно, что-то типа этого, в вашем случае проще всего создать публичный метод `public string AsString() { return string.Join(", ", a); }` а во внешнем коде `label1.Text = a.AsString();`

Comment: В действительности это оказалось правильным решением. Можете оформить ответ, отмечу, как верный.
Благодарю за советы и помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае проще всего создать публичный метод

```
public string AsString()
{
    return string.Join(", ", a);
}
```

А во внешнем коде вызвать

```
label1.Text = a.AsString();
```

Comment: Расширение для массива int? Может всё же нужны входящие данные?

Comment: @Yotic нет, просто метод в классе, который показал автор вопроса.